# Unusual python function wrapper syntax

Tags: python, django-channels, asgi

I'm going through [django channels tutorial](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.html) and I'm baffled by the async_to_sync syntax in the [asgiref.sync module](https://github.com/django/asgiref/blob/e47947e1add08e7103ef514abb63aa9e1e7bc790/asgiref/sync.py#L305)

Specifically

```
async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
    self.room_group_name,
    self.channel_name
)
```

It says async_to_sync is a wrapper, which seems to be an interchangeable term with decorator (please correct me if this is not the case) but I'm unable to find any documentation where decorators have the syntax of

`func_one(func_two)(args)`

What's the flow of this line? is func_one or func_two called first? And how are the return values passed around?

Comment: `async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)` returns a function which takes two params, `self.room_group_name` and `self.channel_name`.

Comment: @Felipe OK, excellent, thanks. Does this syntax have a special name? Is there any documentation that I could read on it? I always thought of functions working from right to left so this is a jarring discovery for me!

Comment: The function `async_to_sync` would indeed be a [`decorator`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators#What_is_a_Decorator), but it's being called directly with the function as opposed to being used with the `@async_to_sync` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
def wrapper(func):
    def inner(*args):
        return (output.uppercase() for outputs in func())

    return inner
```

You can use the decorator `wrapper` in two ways:

```
wrapper(function)("Hello", "World")
```

Or, the more traditional way:

```
@wrapper
def function(*args):
    print(args)

function("Hello", "World")
```

Both outputs:

```
('HELLO', 'WORLD')
```

The function `wrapper` returns the function `inner()`, which modifies the output of the `function()` call. Some pseudocode:

```
wrapper(function)("Hello", "World")
    inner("Hello", "World")
        output = function("Hello", "World")
        output = output.modified # ("HELLO", "WORLD")
    return output # ("HELLO", "WORLD")
```

Comment: Ahhh brilliant, that makes sense. I'll accept this as soon as I'm able. So this is just another way to use a decorator?

Comment: The generalized idea of a decorator is a function that takes another function as an input, and returns a function. So yes. :)

Comment: Yup, my pleasure. :)